# How do i add variables to a regression that influence the coefficient beta?

Tags: panel-data

I am doing a research on the impact of macro-economic ageing on productivity.

I have made my basic regression which investigates the impact of the changeing age structures on productivity. But now i want to add variables to my regression who could influence the impact of ageing on productivity. I would like to see coefficients of how these new variables influence the impact of ageing on productivity.

I think my regression should look like this but i don't know how to perform it in a statistical application 
[image]

Is there a name for a model like this?

Thanks in advance,

Louis

Answer (score 0):

In general, a model of the form

$Y_i=X_i^T\beta(Z_i)+\epsilon_i$

is termed a "varying coefficient specification" (alternatively "smooth coefficient specification"). These are often of the semiparametric form. You might see the function npscoef() in the R package np for a kernel-based implementation.

Comment: It is just a linear regression model, or at most "linear regression model with interaction term".